# How __init__ works for inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, subclass, python-class

I cant have 2 init methods in one class because of function overloading. However, why is it possible that when initializing a subclass, im able to define a new `__init__` method, and use the `super().__init__` method or the parentclass init method within the subclass `__init__` method. i'm just a little confused by the concept of 2 `__init__` methods functioning at the same time

```py
class Employee:
    emps = 0
    def __init__(self,name,age,pay):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.pay = pay

    
class Developer(Employee):
    def __init__(self,name,age,pay,level):
        Employee.__init__(self,name,age,pay)
        self.level = level
```

Comment: There is a big difference between trying to define `__init__` twice in the same class, and defining it *once* in each of two different classes.

Comment: `Employee.__init__` is one method; `Developer.__init__` is another. Calling `Employee.__init__` explicitly should be self-explanatory. To be fair, calling `super().__init__(name, age, pay)` doesn't make it immediately obvious what's going on if you don't know what `super` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cant have 2 init methods in one class because of function overloading.

Partially true. You can't have 2 `__init__` methods *in the same class* because the language *lacks* function overloading. (Libraries can partially restore a limited form of function overloading; see `functools.singledispatchmethod` for an example.)

> i'm just a little confused by the concept of 2 **init** methods functioning at the same time

But you aren't trying to overload `__init__`. You are *overriding* `__init__`, providing a different definition for `Developer` than the definition it inherits from `Employer`. (In fact, `Employer` is overriding `__init__` as well, using its own definition in place of the one it inherits from `object`.) Each class has only one definition.

---

In your definition of `Developer.__init__`, you are simply making an explicit call to the inherited method to do the initialization common to all instances of `Employee`, before doing the `Developer`-specific initialization on the same object.

---

Using `super`, you are using a form of dynamic lookup to let the method resolution order for instance of `Developer` decide what the "next" version of `__init__` available to `Developer` to call. For single inheritance, the benefit is little more than avoiding the need to hard-code a reference to `Employee`. But for multiple inheritance, `super` is crucial to ensuring that all inherited methods (both the ones you know about and the ones you may not) get called, and more importantly, are called in the right order.

A full discussion of how to properly use `super` is beyond the scope of this question, I think, but I'll show your two classes rewritten to make the best use of `super`, and refer you to [Python's `super()` considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) for more information.

```
# Main rules:
#  1. *All* classes use super().__init__, even if you are only inheriting
#     from object, because you don't know who will use you as a base class.
#  2. __init__ should use keyword arguments, and be prepared to accept any
#     keyword arguments.
#  3. All keyword arguments that don't get assigned to your own parameters
#     are passed on to an inherited __init__() to process.

class Employee:
    emps = 0
    def __init__(self, *, name, age, pay, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.pay = pay

    
class Developer(Employee):
    def __init__(self, *, level, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.level = level


d1 = Developer(name="Alice", age=30, pay=85000, level=1)
```

---

To whet your appetite for the linked article, consider

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, *, x, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x = x


class B:
    def __init__(self, *, y, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.y = y


class C1(A, B):
    pass


class C2(B, A):
    pass


c1 = C1(x=1, y=2)
c2 = C2(x=4, y=3)
assert c1.x == 1 and c1.y == 2
assert c2.x == 4 and c2.y == 3
```

The assertions all pass, and both `A.__init__` and `B.__init__` are called as intended when `c1` and `c2` are created.

Answer (score 0):

The `super()` function is used to give access to methods and properties of a parent or sibling class

check out: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-super/